# x11 - simulate a button click

Tags: x11, xlib

I have a window id and I want to simulate a button click on that window. I can do that using XSendEvent function, but then I need to know a button position. Does exists other way to do this ( for example using a button title ) ?

Comment: As far as X11 is concerned, there are no "button titles" or "buttons" for that matter. There are only windows. Even if your button is its own window (this happens with some, mostly older, toolkits) there's slim chance you can find it by title. **TL;DR no there isn't.**

Comment: There may be a way to traverse the window hierarchy and calculate the position by summing the offsets of containing windows along the path, but you'd probably find the position by trial and error in less time.